# Jquery onClick functions wont work with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, onclick

i have made a function with Jquery that changes a links color when i click it... The code works just fine when i link my link to #(hash), but i mix it with php it won't work?

This is my PHP which is working just fine:

```
<?php
    $pages_dir = 'pages';
    if (!empty($_GET['p'])) {
        $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
        unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);
        $p = $_GET['p'];
        if (in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)) {
            include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');
        } else {
            echo '******.';
        }
    } else {
        include($pages_dir.'/hjem.inc.php');
    }
?>
```

And my links in my HTML which is working just fine too:

```
href="index.php?p=*********"
```

But now i wanna apply a effect that makes the background-color of my links a different color with i OnClick effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $targetElement = $("*** This is to my links ***");
        $targetElement.click(function() {
            $targetElement.removeClass("changeColor")
            $(this).addClass("changeColor");
    });
});
```

And some css:

```
#****** ul li a:link.changeColor{
    background-color:black;
}
```

The Jquery only works when i href my links to # and i want it to work anyway with my php code of course :)

Comment: the `hash` symbol is a partial fragment identifier, without the string of the identifier being provided, it will simply return you to the document, which will be the top of the page. If you're already at the top, you won't notice it. If you're trying to stop the link from clicking through and changing, then you need to prevent the default behavior with `.click(function(e){` <-- see how we added the `e`? that's the `event`. now inside of that function, `e.preventDefault();` the link will no longer click through. It was hard to understand your question, but I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

prevent the default event of anchor element, so change:

```
$targetElement.click(function() {
  $targetElement.removeClass("changeColor")
  $(this).addClass("changeColor");
});
```

to

```
$targetElement.click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   //get href tag and load content
   var $this = $(this), href = $this.attr("href"), $that = $this;
   $("#someElementId").load(href, function() {
       $targetElement.removeClass("changeColor")
       $that.addClass("changeColor");
   });
});
```

Do you mean something like this

Comment: In this case the requested page will not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the link, browser redirects to the href of the link.

You have 2 options:

1) All will be done by AJAX - you will load content of requested page by ajax and then you will stop to propagating click event, so browser will not redirect. You can do it by returning `false` from event handler or by calling `e.preventDefault()`.

2) Use CSS:

```
ul li a:active {
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: I dont know how the AJAX thing works, but the css code does not work :(